# Is it possible to inline multiple javax validation annotations and express as one message?

Tags: java, validation, constraints

I'm currently getting a bit more familiar with javax validation and custom constraints, and was wondering if it was possible to inline multiple constraints together and report them as a single violation, rather than creating my own custom contraint annotation?

e.g. something like the below (syntax obviously not valid, but hopefully you get the idea)

```
constraint {
  @NotNull
  @Size(min = 2, max = 14)
  @CheckCase(CaseMode.UPPER)
}
@ReportAsSingleViolation
private String license

@NotNull
private String name
```

Answer (score 0):

This is possible by [defining Groups](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/validator/reference/en-US/html_single/#chapter-groups).

Comment: While I appreciate now knowing more about Groups/Group Sequence, I believe it doesn't quite achieve what I want. Really the crux of what I want is the 'ReportAsSingleViolation' functionality; I would like to only have one violation come out when ANY of the constraints goes wrong. Groups seem a nice way of collating similar checks together and then ordering them, but from what I can see if 2 constraints are in a group and both trigger a violation, you'll be left with 2 violations, not the one I'm after.

Answer (score 0):

Probably if one constraint fails you do not want to check another so use **@GroupSequence**.

It will ensure that it will fail on first error found. Hope it helps.